# How to run multiple lua scripts through a single lua script even if one script fails

Tags: lua

dofile("x/y/m.lua")

dofile("x/y/p.lua")

if m.lua fails due to some issue , p.lua will not run at all, please give me some resolution that i can run both files even if the first one fails and have logs for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function dofile(name)
  local f,err=loadfile(name)
  if f==nil then print(err) end
  local ok,err=pcall(f)
  if not ok then print(err) end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [pcall](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-pcall) to catch Lua errors, possibly like this:

```
local success, result = pcall(dofile, "foo.lua")
```

If `success` is false, the function failed and the error message will be in `result`. If `success` is true, the return values of `dofile` will be in `result`. You can add additional `result` variables. For example:

```
local success, result1, result2, result3 = pcall(dofile, "foo.lua")
```